# Override background image

Tags: html, background-image

I have defined an image in the css file. I would like to overwrite it in the html.

File css

```
    .wrapper.style3 {
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-image: url("../images/overlay.png"), url("../images/banner.jpg");
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

File html

```
    <section id="four" class="wrapper style3 special">
      <div class="container">
         <header class="major">
            <h2>Aenean elementum ligula</h2>
            <p>Feugiat sed lorem ipsum magna</p>
         </header>
         <ul class="actions">
           <li><a href="#" class="button special big">Get in touch</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I want to change the "banner.jpg" image in the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline style, `style='background-image: url(...),url(...)'`

```
<section id="four" class="wrapper style3 special" style="background-image: url(...), url(...)">
  <div class="container">
     <header class="major">
        <h2>Aenean elementum ligula</h2>
        <p>Feugiat sed lorem ipsum magna</p>
     </header>
     <ul class="actions">
       <li><a href="#" class="button special big">Get in touch</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```